# Spark doesn't use predicate pushdown for ADLS Gen2

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

*Why Spark doesn't do predicate pushdown for Spark and ADLS Gen 2 (blob storage) in my case?* From articles [like this](https://www.blue-granite.com/blog/10-things-to-know-about-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2) I know that ADLS Gen 2 support predicate pushdown. *But does Spark works with ADLS Gen 2 API properly to ensure predicat pushdown?*

```
# Folder structure example `<base_path>/NAME=ABC/YEAR=2019/MONTH=05/part-xxxx-.snappy.parquet`
spark_session.read \
    .parquet('<base_path>') \
    .filter((F.col('NAME') == 'ABC') & (F.col('YEAR') == 2019) & (F.col('MONTH') == 5)) \
    .explain()
```

From output you can see PySpark use simple `RemoteServiceExec filter` instead of `PushedFilter`. AFAIK, it means Spark doesn't use predicate pushdown for the query.

P.S. I'm running the job in client deploy mode through databricks-connect

Output:

```
RemoteServiceExec filter {
  condition {
    sql_expr {
      sql_repr: "((('#non-sql-expr-183d4706-d0e7-476a-823c-efe0de41914a' = 'ABC') AND ('#non-sql-expr-823ed3f2-b08f-4d00-88c1-29f45d08c43e' = 2019)) AND ('#non-sql-expr-a361bb1a-085f-4948-8fa5-7e1e14f835ee' = 5))"
      embedded_non_sql_exprs {
        uuid: "#non-sql-expr-823ed3f2-b08f-4d00-88c1-29f45d08c43e"
        expr {
          named_expr {
            attr {
              attr_ref {
                name: "YEAR"
                dataType {
                  sql_repr: "INT"
                }
                nullable: true
                metadata {
                  json_repr: "{}"
                }
                expr_id {
                  id: 39
                  jvm_id: "929051d7-3030-4e2c-bf57-923aa610f40e"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      embedded_non_sql_exprs {
        uuid: "#non-sql-expr-183d4706-d0e7-476a-823c-efe0de41914a"
        expr {
          named_expr {
            attr {
              attr_ref {
                name: "NAME"
                dataType {
                  sql_repr: "STRING"
                }
                nullable: true
                metadata {
                  json_repr: "{}"
                }
                expr_id {
                  id: 38
                  jvm_id: "929051d7-3030-4e2c-bf57-923aa610f40e"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      embedded_non_sql_exprs {
        uuid: "#non-sql-expr-a361bb1a-085f-4948-8fa5-7e1e14f835ee"
        expr {
          named_expr {
            attr {
              attr_ref {
                name: "MONTH"
                dataType {
                  sql_repr: "INT"
                }
                nullable: true
                metadata {
                  json_repr: "{}"
                }
                expr_id {
                  id: 40
                  jvm_id: "929051d7-3030-4e2c-bf57-923aa610f40e"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  child {
    logical_relation {
      relation {
        data_frame_read_spec {
          user_specified_source: "parquet"
          paths: "abfss://<base_path>"
        }
      }
      schema {
        ...
      }
      uuid: "da53053d-5e34-4c8d-8bab-f7a30dfefde4"
    }
  }
}
serialization_context {
}
```

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the query to just year=2019 as a test?Also applying a schema to the read. I’m curious that the year and month attributes show as nullable. I don’t think that is correct. I’ve never checked the plan for a push down but I know it works on gen2 as I have queries that would take hours if it wasn’t. I will try to get an explain on one and see how it compares.

Comment: @simon_dmorias thanks for you suggestion! I will have a chance to try during the next few days

Comment: I use parquet on local file system and s3 and I do see predicate pushdown. I thought it is a property of parquet and has nothing to do with storage technology like ADLS Gen 2. Can you please get the physical execution plan of the job run (by activating history server)